# Is a 2 bit one time pad just as secure as a 128 bit one time pad?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

Obviously, it would be easier to stumble across the answer, but you still couldn't be sure it's correct. So it's still theoretically secure?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography? What do you mean by two-bit? Encrypting two bit by two-bit and what is 128-bit OTP?

Comment: How do you define OTP? A 2bit one time pad is as secure as 128bit for encrypting messages. By the definition of OTP you can however only encrypt 2 plaintext bits

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they both satisfy perfect secrecy, but with a 2-bit OTP you can only encrypt a 2-bit message once.